# how to improve speed with using RallyAPIForJava

Tags: rally

Now, I use RallyApiForJava to get story from rally with getRequest method.It's very slow when get about 500 stories from rally.How to improve the speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limiting the scope helps performance. Here is an example of limiting the query by LastUpdateDate, scoping the request to a project and fetching only some fields:

```
int x = -30;
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cal.add( Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, x);
Date nDaysAgoDate = cal.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat iso = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ");
QueryRequest defectRequest = new QueryRequest("Defect");
defectRequest.setProject(projectRef);
defectRequest.setFetch(new Fetch(new String[] {"Name", "FormattedID","State","Priority"}));
defectRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("LastUpdateDate", ">", iso.format(nDaysAgoDate)));
```

Hydrating collections (e.g. Tasks on User Stories) requires a separate request, but if you only need a count of items in the collection, you may save time and not hydrate the collection. CRUD examples available in the [User Guide](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava/wiki/User-Guide) illustrate this API extensively and I don't think that on the user side ,as far as the custom code, there are ways to make it faster other than to limit the results to only what's necessary.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I want to get all the stories and tasks information for analyzing purpose,Can you recommend a way to get these data.

Comment: Not binding the query will give you all stories, but it will be an expensive query if the data is large, and performance may suffer. The note about hydrating collections still applies: it requires a separate call. See this example of getting tasks of stories: https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/rally-java-rest-apps/blob/master/GetTasksOfStories.java

Comment: Thank you! I know how to do it!